# Difference between "luego" and "entonces"

Tags: significado, adverbios, diferencias-entre-palabras

What is the difference between 'Luego' and 'entonces'?

I know they both mean "then". Do they mean other things as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Luego** is generally quite specific to time and in isolation might be most accurately translated as *later on*. In some countries, it can also substitute for *después*: *luego de hacer algo*

**Entonces** has a bit more of a connotation of *and therefore* or *so (then)* when used with that same future-oriented sense. It cannot have the meaning *after [something]* as in the *luego de [algo]* construction. It also can have a past-oriented meaning —that *luego* lacks— meaning *back then*.

Comment: Gracias mucho!! SO you use luego for as later on but entonces for therefore, am I right???

Comment: You can still use entonces for later/afterward. It's going to be preferable if the action takes places afterwards and as a result/response to the previous one. Think of it like in English *so then*. Actually, in general entonces can also be used for *so*, so (haha) I'll update my answer.

Comment: SO you can use it also like so then??

Comment: What does "luego de" mean?

Comment: @0x499602D2 *luego de hablar* = *después de hablar* = *after speaking*. It's not used in all countries, though.

Comment: In Mexico if you say _"Luego luego"_, it means _immediately_, _at once_ or _right away_. Something you just can't do with _entonces_.

Comment: both mean then, but the luego can mean later and entonces can mean so.

Comment: The exact word I would use to match _entonces_ is _consequently_.